How do we know that the euclidean algorithm produces the greatest common factor and not just one of the common factors?
I'm trying to develop an intuitive sense for why the euclidean algorithm is true, and I'm stuck on how to prove that it's the greatest common factor vs just A common factor.  So far I can understand the algorithm by putting the numbers on a number line.  For instance, finding the gcf of 15 and 25.  Whatever factor it ends up being  will evenly divide 15 and then we know that it must also evenly divide the space left over between 15 and 25, otherwise it's not a common factor. So we just repeat it now with the difference and the smaller number until a is the same as b, which ends up being our GCF.

So

$gcd(25,15)$
$gcd(15,10)$
$gcd(10, 5)$
$gcd(5, 5) = 5$

The problem I'm having is how do we know the algorithm produces the greatest factor and not just one of the factors that aren't necessarily the greatest?  I haven't found a way to intuitively think of that.

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Are you familiar with Bezout’s identity and the universal definition of gcd?

Consider positive integers $a, b$ with $a\gt b$.
If $b$ divides $a$ then $b$ must be the greatest common divisor because no number larger than $b$ divides $b$.
If $b$ does not divide $a$ then we can find $q,r$ such that $$a=qb+r\implies a-qb=r$$ so any number that divides both $a$ and $b$ must divide $r$.
If $r$ divides both $a$ and $b$, then it must be the largest because any number that divides both $a$ and $b$ must divide $r$ and no number larger than $r$ can divide $r$.
Continuing in this manner, we use the same argument on each successive remainder. Eventually, we get a remainder $r_i$ that does divide all of the previous numbers and since it also has the property that any number that divides $a$ and $b$ must divide $r_i$, that number is the greatest common divisor.

One can prove the following lemma: $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a,b+ka)$ for any integer $k$.
If we believe this lemma, then it's easy to deduce that the Euclidean algorithm really does arrive at the greatest common factor, since every step in the Euclidean algorithm replaces one of the numbers $b$ by itself plus a multiple of the other number. (We also check by hand that $\gcd(a,0) = a$ for any nonzero integer $a$.)
The standard proof of that lemma does consider all common factors, not just a particular one (so the OP's intuition is right that it's needed somewhere).
